# Unable to inject Captor with QuarkusTest

Tags: mockito, quarkus

I am trying to write integration tests for Quarkus using Mockito, but I fail using Argument captor.
Here is a minimal (not) working example :

```
@QuarkusTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SimpleTest {

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Context> contextArgumentCaptor;

    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        System.out.println(contextArgumentCaptor);
    }

}
```

contextArgumentCaptor is "null".
If I remove @QuarkusTest, contextArgumentCaptor is created.

It also works with @QuarkusTest and direct Argument creator :

```
@QuarkusTest
public class ConfigTest {

    private ArgumentCaptor<Context> contextArgumentCaptor;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        contextArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Context.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void givenValidCloudEvent_whenHandleHandoverFunction_ThenHandoverStarted() {
        System.out.println(contextArgumentCaptor);
    }
}
```

So it is really the combinaison of @QuarkusTest with @Captor that doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using `@QuarkusTest` along with the `@Captor` will not work correctly. You must create the captor yourself